# PHP check for valid parameter passed through the URL in XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt, parameters, hyperlink

I have the following XML that stores 2 movie ID's and their titles

```
<movies
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">

<movie movieID="1">
    <title>Movie 1</title>
</movie>

<movie movieID="2">
    <title>Movie 2</title>
</movie>
</movies>
```

My XSL displays movie titles as hyperlinks that take the user to movie_details page to display movie information based on the ID that was passed through the URL.

movies_list.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Movies list</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/movies/movie"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
  <xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">movie_details.php?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="@movieID"/></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>
```

This is my movie_details.php file

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('test.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('movie_details.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

$params = $_GET['movieID'];
$proc->setParameter('', 'movieID', $params);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
?>
```

I would like to do the following parameter validation in *movie_details.php*:

1. Check that movieID passed through the URL is valid and exists in the XML file. If I manually change the URL in my browser to `myserveraddress.com/movie_details.php?movieID=3`, 
   I get a blank page because `movieID=3` does not exist in the XML file and there is nothing to display.

   If movieID is invalid and does not exist in the xml, then I would like the page to redirect me to `index.php`
2. Check that movieID parameter is passed through the URL at all. For example if I manually change the URL in my browser to `myserveraddress.com/movie_details.php`, the page should redirect me to `index.php` as there are no parameters passed in the URL.

Comment: Where do you hit the roadblock to do that?

Comment: I'm very new to PHP and I'm not quite sure how to do that. I need to somehow check that $_GET['movieID'] is a valid parameter. but how can I do that in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by doing the following IF statement:

```
if (isset($_GET["movieID"]) && !empty($_GET["movieID"]) && ($_GET["movieID"] <="2"))
{
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('test.xml');

    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('movie_details.xsl');

    $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    $params = $_GET['movieID'];
    $proc->setParameter('', 'movieID', $params);

    echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
}
else
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

It might not be the best solution out there, but as a PHP beginner I am quite happy with the validation it provides.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an element with a specific attribute value exists in your `$xml` `DOMDocument`, you can make use of `DOMXPath`:

```
$movieID    = 3;
$expression = sprintf('boolean(//movie[@movieID="%d"])', $movieID);

$exists = $xpath->evaluate($expression);

if (!$exists) {
    echo "Invalid movieID!\n";
}
```

Comment: I've updated my movie_details.php code with your solution but I keep getting an error "Undefined variable: xpath" "Fatal error: Call to a member function evaluate() on a non-object"